# Least-upper-bound property Rudin book

Tags: real-analysis

In baby Rudin:

**1.10 Definition:**

An ordered set S is said to have the least-upper-bound property if the following is true:

If E $\subset$ S, E is not empty, and E is bounded above, then sup E exists in S.

I find the way it's written to be weird, shouldn't he instead have written:

If E $\subset$ S, E is not empty, and E is bounded above, **and** sup E exists in S.

I mean it's a definition, he can't come to conclusions in a definition.. Please someone explain I'm really confused thanks a lot!!

Comment: Every linearly ordered set satisfies your definition.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're saying..My question is why is he putting the definition in the form of an implication? it's in the form A,B-->C But why? I don't know what a linearly ordered set is put thanks either way!

Comment: Because he's suppressing the "For all E" (and doing other things I don't like). $\;$

Answer (score 6):

It should actually be as follows:

An ordered set S is said to have the least-upper-bound property if **and only if** the following is true:

**For all E**, $\;\;\;$ if $\;$ $\:$[$\{\hspace{-0.02 in}\}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) $\neq$ E $\subset$ S$\:$ and E is bounded above $\:\:$ then $\:\:$ sup E exists in S $\;\;\;$.

.

Comment: very clearly stated

Comment: I find the blueness of your empty set philosophically curious.

Comment: @Pete : $\:$ What color are links? $\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky: They're blue.  I understand the phenomenon and am not objecting to it.  It's just that I read your answer and thought, "Hmm, I wasn't expecting the empty set to be blue".  Then I realized what a striking statement that was.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with putting implications in a definition, and in this case, it's quite necessary.  If the implication is true for a given ordered set $S$, then the set has the least upper bound property, and otherwise, it does not have the least upper bound property.

For example, if $S=\mathbb{Q}$ is the ordered set of rational numbers, then the implication fails: The set $E=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x^2<2\}$ is nonempty and bounded above, but $\sup E$ does not exist.  Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}$ does *not* have the least upper bound property.

On the other hand, consider the ordered set $S=\mathbb{Z}$, the integers.  Any subset of integers $E \subset \mathbb{Z}$ which is nonempty and bounded above must have a maximum element, and this maximum element is $\sup E$.  Therefore , $\mathbb{Z}$ does have the least upper bound property.

Later, you will prove that the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property, which is the characteristic property that distinguishes it from sets like $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I was looking for!!, it's annoying that I can't upvote your post though..